# What does document.body.offsetHeight do before window.print()?

Tags: javascript, gmail

Sniffing gmail's *Print all* link source code, there's something like this:

```
<script>
function Print(){document.body.offsetHeight;window.print()};
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Print()">
```

What does `document.body.offsetHeight` do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It forces WebKit based browsers to load the complete set of content before printing (including images, styles, etc.)